# Does Python support "infinite" float precision?

Tags: python, floating-point

I did study how binary numbers are stored in computers, and IEEE754 floating point representation.

What I want to know is if Python can extend float up to user set precision. Or if I can simulate that, storing chunks of these bits that represent the decimal number and sticking them up together later.

Comment: Not directly. See [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/).